# Bootstrap span elements in row full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want items inside `row` to take full width and to be evenly distributed. First item should at be at leftmost and right item should be at rightmost. Elements in the middle should be evenly apart from each other. I want them to be aligned with labels on x axis (see image below). There can be **n labels** (and therefore n items inside row) so solution must be flexible. I am using **Bootstrap v3.3.7**.

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper hidden">
    <canvas id="testsRegression"></canvas>
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">87664</a>
      <a href="#">87735</a>
      <a href="#">87816</a>
      <a href="#">87947</a>
      <a href="#">88038</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: What charting library are you using? As previously stated flexbox will evenly space items but will not guarantee alignment with the axis labels.

You may be able to hook into the label creation and override it to make them links.

Comment: I am using Chart.js. The problem is that it draws the graph on canvas and canvas doesn't support links out of the box, you kind of have to hack it to work. The code becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

used `flex-box` to achieve it.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading {
  align-self: center;
}

.row{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between; }


body{
margin: 0}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper hidden">
    <canvas id="testsRegression"></canvas>
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">87664</a>
      <a href="#">87735</a>
      <a href="#">87816</a>
      <a href="#">87947</a>
      <a href="#">88038</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First and last item are not aligned. They should be placed at leftmost and rightmost as they can be ([see image](https://i.imgur.com/eiIY6DQ.png)).

Comment: but in the snippet result it is showing correctly right??

Comment: Yes, weird. I will check what's wrong with my code.

Comment: check the width of "OK" text div